# Why .NET Core Source Code need a lot of "#if !CORECLR static #endif" on method?

Tags: c#, .net-core

E.g: Github [dotnet/runtime/String.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/String.cs) source code

```
        private
#if !CORECLR
        static
#endif
        string Ctor(char[]? value)
        {
            if (value == null || value.Length == 0)
                return Empty;

            string result = FastAllocateString(value.Length);

            Buffer.Memmove(
                elementCount: (uint)result.Length, // derefing Length now allows JIT to prove 'result' not null below
                destination: ref result._firstChar,
                source: ref MemoryMarshal.GetArrayDataReference(value));

            return result;
        }
```

[image]
[image]

It seems to work pretty well without adding this, and the maintenance cost will become higher.
Is it for performance reasons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Why .NET Core Source Code need a lot of “#if !CORECLR static #endif” on method? · Issue #46246 · dotnet/runtime](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/46246)

Microsoft team answer:

benaadams:

> That file is in the `/libraries/` Is shared between Mono, CoreClr and CoreRT; as the majority of the method is identical other than the `static` I assume it's less maintenance just to `#if` the `static` rather than duplicate the code

jkotas:

> It would be nice to fix the CoreCLR convention for string constructors so that this ifdef is not necessary. The convention used on other runtimes is a tiny bit more efficient (avoids unnecessary dummy `this` pointer).